Why is editing a staged question so different from editing a posted question?
I tried to fix code formatting of this staged question https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78740556.
I didn't manage to get the formatting right, because there is no preview, and the top bar icons are very different than usually. Why is that?

It uses the Stacks Editor which is the editor that is used for all new features. I believe there are still plans to make it the only editor network-wide but the timeline is unclear.

"I didn't manage to get the formatting right, because there is no preview," But there is a preview available, it's below the body or can be displayed in rich text; I guess you were in Markdown only mode, not markdown with preview?

You can get a preview with the stacks editor by clicking into the markdown with preview mode. That however isn't a guarantee that the preview will match the output.

@KevinB thanks I found the buttom. Anyhow, I feel its a bit against the idea of the stagingground to provide a more smooth entry for newcomers when they have to face two different editors (and even other users have difficulties to explain them ;)

100% agree, but it seems stack is hellbent on pushing their new unfinished editor. it doesn't even support stack snippets.

@HenryEcker If they make the Stacks Editor the only editor network-wide without any way to opt-out, I will go on strike by not editing. I like the old editor so much more.

I recall (citation needed) that the "normal "editor doesn't support the SG, as it uses the ask wizard which, also, isn't supported by the normal editor, owing to the fact that the question is split into 2 parts (a details and expectation section). I agree that inconsistency isn't great, and that development on the Stack Editor appears to have been stalled for years despite it being pushed in new products.

The Staging Ground uses the stacks-editor, which has been in development for some time and is only used in a few parts of the site (e.g., SO Meta via setting). It's supposed to replace the old editor at some point.

In that case, IMO, the stacks editor has a long way to go before it is usable.  I'd like to work on some Staging Ground questions, but I've largely given up because I don't understand how the UI works.

@JonathanLeffler you're not the only one to think that. See the announcement post from a few years ago. It's actually improved a lot since then, but (IMO) until they have a proper preview pane alongside the markdown editor, it's unusable. I also really don't like that they now default links to inline style [text](link) over reference style [text][1] .... [1]: link

@Robotnik you can turn on a preview in the upper right corner (except on Teams, where this is inexplicably disabled).

@Robotnik: Funny — I prefer the inline style over the reference style.  For one or two links, there isn't much difference.  If there are 30 links, it's a lot easier to keep track of what's what if the URL is next to the descriptive text.

@JonathanLeffler To be clear: this is a personal preference, IMO too many embedded inline URLs makes reading the raw markdown a real chore, having to dodge around links embedded in paragraphs. I understand it's not everyone's preference so I don't go out of my way to change another post's link style when editing. I also tend to give reference links names, rather than rely on the default numbers, eg [text][short-desc] ... [short-desc]: link`. It makes more sense when you have many and/or long URLs, whether you link to the same URL more than once, and makes tooltips easier too, IMO.

A good example of the extreme of this: Arqade's screenshot of the week hall of fame. Example post - View Source

I just ran into this again, on two posts.  I can't type the way that's worked for the last 15 years or so.  I loathe the staging ground editor.  I have no idea how a beginner is supposed to get it to work to produce decently indented code, but I can understand why most of the questions I get to look at have badly formatted code.  There had better be a way to turn of the code editor nonsense.  If that ever makes it into the main SO site as the only way to work with code, I shall leave SO.
